# Вывод года из переменной типа дата

Tags: php, html

Подскажите начинающему программисту как вывести из переменной типа дата только год.
А то он выводит всю дату,например 2010-10-10. А надо только 2010.

Comment: если бы я нашел,сюда бы не полез

Comment: Вот это я и пробовал писать,у меня получается везде 1970 год.То что вы написали вычитает из сегодней даты,ту дату которую мне надо вывести.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать дату в нормальный вид?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369696/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Answer (score 2):

Но все равно Спасибо, Влад. Я в ваших ссылках нашел нужное.Вот так надо:

```
$date="2010-04-30";
$y = date('Y',strtotime($date));
echo $y;
```