# Как преобразовать дату в нормальный вид?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть дата в базе данных. При выборке данных получают такую дату -

**2014-10-22**.

Как преобразовать это в нормальный вид, чтобы было

**22.10.2014 г.**

Люди добрые, помогите!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
date("d.m.Y", strtotime('2014-22-10'))
```

Comment: Круто, а как сделать, чтобы на стороне MYSql эту проблему решить? Т.е. когда я делаю запрос, чтобы он сразу возвращал мне в нужном формате.

Answer (score 6):

MySQL

```
DATE_FORMAT("2014-10-22",'%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: И кого выбрать?) Оба помогли.)))

Comment: @duddeniska, того, кто первый ответил. Ваш К.О.

Answer (score 1):

В запросах неудобно, придется постоянно повторять при каждом случае шаблон форматирования, удобнее запрашивать `unix_timestamp(column)`, а затем уже сразу форматировать результат одной на весь сайт функцией php;

Ну и, соответственно, при записи, опять же, возложить проблему на db engine и, преобразовав в timestamp полученную дату, посылать ее в `from_unixtime($column);`.